# How do I use a specific columns value in Node JS using SQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, azure

I was wondering how to I select a specific column to save to a variable in my function. I need both values which is why I have a query getting both at once. I'm using Node JS with an Azure SQL Database and I'm using tedious for my SQL NPM plugin. I'm fairly new to this so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Side note: the request "on done" at the very bottom that returns the row count isn't doing anything. If anyone knows why I'd love to know, it's not important but I'm just curious.

```
function Charge(chipId, LocID) {
        request = new Request("SELECT car_id, userOwner FROM Cars WHERE carChipId = '" + chipId + "'", function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        var result = "";
        request.on('row', function (columns) {
            columns.forEach(function (column) {
                if (column.value === null) {
                    console.log('NULL');
                } else {
                    result += column.value + " ";
                }
            });
            console.log(result);
            result = "";
        });

        request.on('done', function (rowCount, more) {
            console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
        });
        connection.execSql(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying the following to select a specific column saved to the variable:

```
function charge(chipId) {
  var carId = '';
  var userOwner = '';

  request = new Request(`SELECT car_id, userOwner FROM Cars WHERE carChipId = '${chipId}'`, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  request.on('row', function(columns) {

    carId = columns[0].value;
    userOwner = columns[1].value;
    console.log('carId: ', carId);
    console.log('userOwner: ', userOwner);
  });

  connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Another option is that you can set `options.useColumnNames` as `true` (Default: false) to return rows as key-value collections. Below is the code example.

```
var config = {
  userName: '<userName>',
  password: '<password>',
  server: '<serverName>.database.windows.net',

  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    database: '<database>',
    useColumnNames: true
  }
};

var connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on('connect', function(err) {
  charge('<chipId>');
});

function charge(chipId) {
  var carId = '';
  var userOwner = '';

  request = new Request(`SELECT car_id, userOwner FROM Cars WHERE carChipId = '${chipId}'`, function(err) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    }
  });

  request.on('row', function(columns) {
    carId = columns.car_id.value;
    userOwner = columns.userOwner.value;
    console.log('carId: ', carId, ' userOwner: ', userOwner);
  });

  connection.execSql(request);
}
```

If you wanna `Event: done` be triggered, please use `connection.execSqlBatch(request)` instead of `connection.execSql(request)`. For details, please refer to http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_execSqlBatch.

Comment: I also can't seem to do more than one request from a single `connection.on('connect',` for whatever reason, is there something else I should know?

Comment: There is some documentation at http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html that states that this is not supported. `Only one request at a time may be executed on a connection.` You can use mutiple connections instead. [This post](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/236) may be helpful.

Comment: Ok, I made another post about this topic would you mind reviewing my situation to make sure it would work?

Comment: I looked into this and I will share details after lunch.